# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type Models is less accessible than method.AlbumsController.Create

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use Entity Framework with MVC in asp.net code first approach
Below there are simple two classed in Model

```
class Album
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

class MusicStoreContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

There is an action "Create" in Controller named as albumController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="AlbumId,Title,Price")] Album album)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Albums.Add(album);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(album);
}
```

So the problem is when I run the website Error comes out..
Error :Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'WebApplication2.Models.Album' is less accessible than method 'WebApplication2.Content.AlbumsController.Create(WebApplication2.Models.Album)'

Comment: Just change `class Album` to `public class Album`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class Album has default access level - internal. And method of your controller is public. So you have to change your Album like this: public class Album...

Comment: Thanks for the Help Egor Semenenko